# How to allocate memory for my data structure in C

Tags: c, pointers, data-structures, malloc

I don't understand why my code is printing out garbage variables after the user enters in their data. In the process of learning Data Structures, linked lists, and memory allocation in my intro to C class. Thanks for the help!

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <malloc.h>
#include <string.h>

typedef struct AutoMobilesInfo
{
    char *Manufacturer, *ModelNameOfCar, *ColorOfCar;
    int YearOfCar;
    struct AutoMobilesInfo *next;
} Car;

void EnterCarInfo(Car *Info)
{
    Info = (Car *)malloc(sizeof(Car));
    Info->Manufacturer = (char *)malloc(12 *(sizeof(char)));
    Info->ModelNameOfCar = (char *)malloc(12 *(sizeof(char)));
    Info->ColorOfCar = (char *)malloc(12 *(sizeof(char)));

    printf("Please enter the car's manufacturer: \n");
    scanf(" %s", Info->Manufacturer);
    printf("Please enter the car's model: \n");
    scanf(" %s", Info->ModelNameOfCar);
    printf("Please enter the car's color: \n");
    scanf(" %s", Info->ColorOfCar);
    printf("Please enter the year the car was made: \n");
    scanf("%d", &Info->YearOfCar);
}

void PrintedOutCarInfo(Car *host)
{
    host = (Car *)malloc(sizeof(Car));
    host->Manufacturer = (char *)malloc(12 *(sizeof(char)));
    host->ModelNameOfCar = (char *)malloc(12 *(sizeof(char)));
    host->ColorOfCar = (char *)malloc(12 *(sizeof(char)));

    printf("The car's manufacturer is %s\n", host->Manufacturer);
    printf("The car's model is %s\n", host->ModelNameOfCar);
    printf("The color of the car is %s\n", host->ColorOfCar);
    printf("The year the car was made is %d\n", host->YearOfCar);
}

int main()
{
    Car *Car1;
    Car1 = (Car *) malloc(sizeof(Car));
    EnterCarInfo(Car1);
    PrintedOutCarInfo(Car1);
    free(Car1);

    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You're overwriting the pointer in `PrintedOutCarInfo`. This line

```
host = (Car *)malloc(sizeof(Car));
```

and this line

```
Info = (Car *)malloc(sizeof(Car));
```

the variables `host` and `Info` you passed in are allocated. Change that function to this

```
void PrintedOutCarInfo(Car *host) {
  printf("The car's manufacturer is %s\n", host->Manufacturer);
  printf("The car's model is %s\n", host->ModelNameOfCar);
  printf("The color of the car is %s\n", host->ColorOfCar);
  printf("The year the car was made is %d\n", host->YearOfCar);
}
```

You should also not case the returns from malloc ie do this instead...

```
 Info = malloc(sizeof(Car));
```

Try this...

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <malloc.h>

typedef struct AutoMobilesInfo
{
  char *Manufacturer, *ModelNameOfCar, *ColorOfCar;
  int YearOfCar;
  struct AutoMobilesInfo *next;
} Car;

void EnterCarInfo(Car *Info)
{
  Info->Manufacturer   = malloc(12 * (sizeof(char)));
  Info->ModelNameOfCar = malloc(12 * (sizeof(char)));
  Info->ColorOfCar     = malloc(12 * (sizeof(char)));

  printf("Please enter the car's manufacturer: \n");
  scanf(" %s", Info->Manufacturer);
  printf("Please enter the car's model: \n");
  scanf(" %s", Info->ModelNameOfCar);
  printf("Please enter the car's color: \n");
  scanf(" %s", Info->ColorOfCar);
  printf("Please enter the year the car was made: \n");
  scanf("%d", &Info->YearOfCar);
}

void PrintedOutCarInfo(Car *host) {
  printf("The car's manufacturer is %s\n", host->Manufacturer);
  printf("The car's model is %s\n", host->ModelNameOfCar);
  printf("The color of the car is %s\n", host->ColorOfCar);
  printf("The year the car was made is %d\n", host->YearOfCar);
}

int main()
{
  Car *Car1 = malloc(sizeof(Car));
  EnterCarInfo(Car1);
  PrintedOutCarInfo(Car1);
  free(Car1);
  return 0;
}
```

Comment: First question, how is the compiler in code:blocks able to understand the malloc function if I haven't included the header malloc.h? Second Question, Why didn't I need to allocate memory for my data structure first? As in, I see how you removed the first line in my EnterCarInfo() function.

Comment: I don't know if you need malloc.h or not. I don't on my machine. If you do add it back. You already allocated the of memory for Car1 in main. You passed this to the functions.

Comment: It builds, compiles and runs ok, so I'm note sure. I'll have to ask my professor in our next class time. Ok, I understand now and thank you for your help!

Comment: @MichaelBenton malloc is declared in stdlib.h.

Comment: @MichaelBenton "Why didn't I need to allocate memory for my data structure first?" - uhh, you did? See those `malloc` calls?

Answer (score 0):

The issue is caused by the allocation of memory in PrintedOutCarInfo().
In EnterCarInfo(), you are allocating the memory necessary for Car and its members (strings) and filling them with the user's input.
When you allocate the Car struct and its members again in EnterCarInfo, you are clobbering your references to the original Car structure and its members.
If you remove the first 4 lines of EnterCarInfo(), the program should work.
As a side note, this app is OK for learning/demonstration, but it is not a good idea to allocate a fixed block of memory that will receive user input without enforcing the size limits.  Failing to check limits will open you up for buffer overflow attacks.
Hope this helps.

Comment: This issue is that I must dynamically allocate my data structure and to do so I need those first 4 lines of code. Unless I'm wrong and dynamically allocate means something else that I'm not doing.

Answer (score 0):

As Harry said below, you are overwriting the pointers in **PrintedOutCarInfo()**. That function should look like this:

```
void PrintedOutCarInfo(Car *host)
{
    printf("The car's manufacturer is %s\n", host->Manufacturer);
    printf("The car's model is %s\n", host->ModelNameOfCar);
    printf("The color of the car is %s\n", host->ColorOfCar);
    printf("The year the car was made is %d\n", host->YearOfCar);
}
```

[Malloc()](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/c/malloc) allocates (reserves) a given amount of memory for usage by your application, and then returns a pointer to the address where this chunk of memory begins. You already allocated the needed memory in EnterCarInfo() so when you call Malloc() a second time in PrintedOutCarInfo() you are allocating another space in memory, and then pointing the AutoMobilesInfo's pointers to that new place in memory. The data collected by EnterCarInfo() is still in memory, but its in the old location which is no longer referenced by your instance of AutoMobilesInfo. So, when you printf() the data, you're printing whatever garbage is in the newly allocated chunk of memory.

Comment: Yeah, I understand it a little more clearly now. I did not realize I had allocated it in main as well. Thank you so much!